# Writing or modifying lxpanel and xfce4-panel plugins

Tags: xfce, plugins, lxpanel

I have no programming skills and would like to ask an experienced programmer, how difficult it is to write a new plugin for lxpanel? Or, if possible, to modify the existing xfce4-panel plugin to work with lxpanel, whichever is easier. My particular plugin of interest is the xfce4-netload-plugin. The package and source code for the xfce4-netload-plugin can be found here:
https://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-netload-plugin/start
All panel plugins are .so files and located at:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxpanel/plugins         (for LXDE)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libnetload.so      (for Xfce)
libnetload.so is the Xfce pugin.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You do realize Xfce is GTK3, where as LXDE is GTK2; ie. they are using different toolkits/libraries so the *port* will in effect be a new program and not a modification. LXDE is *deprecated* because it's GTK2 based (the initial port of it to GTK3 was abandoned because the *devs* found GTK3 too heavy; thus the re-port to Qt5 and joining with Razor-Qt team creating the LXQt replacement for LXDE).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I understand that GTK2 and GTK3 apps can coexist on the same system without any problems. I successfully installed xfce4-panel and xfce4-netload-plugin on LXDE desktop with lxsession. No other xfce4 packages were installed and everything works perfectly fine. However, I would prefer to have the netload plugin working inside lxpanel. There must be a way to write an lxpanel plugin in GTK2, performing the same functions as xfce4-netload-plugin.

Comment: GTK2 is *deprecated*, has no concept of modern ideas such as *scaling* etc. as GTK2 & GTK3 are more than a decade of coding apart.. Yes you can *port* it, but that's a re-write of the GTK3 code in `xfce4-netload-plugin` to use GTK2 calls (instead of it's GTK3 calls), recompile to create new binary etc - ie. a programming question.

Comment: I am not a programmer. All I can do is install a package from a repository or download and install .deb package. There is a plugin for lxpanel here:
https://github.com/Denzy7/lxNetSpeedMonitor
However, I couldn't install it because of multiple errors.

Comment: Your last comment doesn't appear to be what this question is about, which "*how difficult it is to write a new plugin for lxpanel*" which I've answered to an extent via comment. If you want to ask about your issue with the last comment (*which isn't in this post's question*) you should ask a new question, or re-write this one to be about that, and have it include all details including OS/release, your commands & actual messages around your issue. LXDE no longer has a Ubuntu team behind it (*Lubuntu is now LXQt only*) so it's upstream Debian code now.

Comment: I finally got a real useful answer to this question from a kind github member Denzy7, who provided the source code and full instructions on how to build and install the plugin. He also helped me to resolve the errors. Thank you so much Dennis!       https://github.com/Denzy7/lxNetSpeedMonitor     I am now perfectly satisfied with my Debian 11 Bullseye LXDE! For me LXDE is more important than Ubuntu, so if Ubuntu abandoned LXDE, I abandoned Ubuntu in favor of Linux distros that still support LXDE, such as Debian, Devuan, Star, AntiX, Q4OS and many others.